# Media Queries Issue in Footer Section

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

> [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNsi8.png) 
>
> In this Screen Size(1024*1366) footer section is not visible

> [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDoQ3.png)
> Here it is Showing Properly

How Can we Resolve this Issue?

Comment: Hi, there is no way we can help without seeing an example of the code and a description of what isn't working. Also in your question there is no second image. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

you need to add auto scroll to the body then the overflow section will be visible:

```
body {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Hi,
I already have implemented this but not working for some Screen sizes as mentioned in Screenshot [image 1]